# Executing maven compile commands from bash sequentially

Tags: bash, maven

I'm trying to build a project with Maven sequentially, with no success.

I tried put the following lines in a script file and called it from bash.

`mvn -f ./cmroad-api/pom.xml clean install corona:package -Ddebug=false
 mvn -f ./cmroad-impl/pom.xml clean install corona:package -Ddebug=false`

The first command runs but the build does not call the second command. I tried putting the `;` like:

`mvn -f ./cmroad-api/pom.xml clean install corona:package -Ddebug=false; mvn -f ./cmroad-impl/pom.xml clean install corona:package -Ddebug=false`.

The output was:

`[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.`

I would be most thankful for any help.

Comment: These modules cmroad, cmroad-impl sounds like they should be build within a multi-module build. So why are you trying to build them manually one by one. Why not letting maven do that job. How does you your folder structure look like?

Comment: absolutely right! they are all part of a parent pom.xml. But if I run maven on that, it complains about a "circle dependency", which is why I'm trying to compile them in a particular order.

Comment: If you have circular references than your build is wrong. Point. You have to solve that first otherwise you are going the wrong way.

Comment: You can add `set -x` at the beginning of a script file to see debug info from bash. Do you have `set -e` flag set? In such case bash will stop at the first error and not run second command if the build fail.

Comment: thank you khmarbaise. That's what I also thought. I really should remove the circular references, I needed a quick solution and didn't have enough time to do it. I'll create a separat thread on that, in the meantime, the question remains: how do I call maven sequentially  (i.e. chaining multiple calls one after another)?

Answer (score 0):

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn".
```

This is the error you would get on typing `mvn mvn`; your script has two `mvn`s on the same line, presumably because something is wrong with your line endings.

Start with a simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo A
echo B
```

and get that working before moving on to Maven. The commands you specify should work when placed in a correctly prepared script. (Although, as khmarbaise says, your project is wrong if you need to build in this order.)